# Why are session variables retained between different users on the same PC?

Tags: php, session, laravel

My Laravel PHP application stores various user interface states using `Session::put()`.

I was surprised to discover that session variables seem to be retained between different users who log in sequentially on one PC. For example:

- log in as user1, set some UI options, log out
- log in as user2, expect to see default UI options, actually see user1's options

I've tried with native and database session drivers.

Why are session variables retained between different users on the same PC? Wouldn't this be regarded a security defect? Is this a Laravel or general PHP issue, or my implementation? What's the correct solution?

Comment: Maybe `Session::regenerate();` after logout helps?

Comment: @DanFromGermany that wont solve the issue. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why are session variables retained between different users on the same
>   PC?

You are mistaking "sessions" and "auth". They are not the same thing. 
You can have a "session" without being logged into Laravel (or most web applications).

When you log in to an application, that is simply added onto your *current* session. But when you logout of the application your *current* session continues, just without the `auth` bit.

> What's the correct solution?

If you want to clear the session of all data - you must flush it:

```
Auth::logout();
Session::flush();
```

*(note - the comment suggestion above to use `Session::regenerate()` is incorrect - that will only regenerate the session ID - not the data - it will remain)*

Comment: this was very helpful. It did occur to me that not all users will log out by explicitly calling the logout method (some may lapse when the session lifetime expires). Wouldn't it be safer to flush the session immediately prior to authenticating, to catch all cases?

Answer (score 4):

> Why are session variables retained between different users on the same PC?

Presumably because they are logging out of your application, but not the user environment for the OS and are not closing the browser either.

> Wouldn't this be regarded a security defect?

It is more a case of bad security practices on the part of the end users.

> Is this a Laravel or general PHP issue, or my implementation? What's the correct solution?

Clear the session data when the user logs out.